# Error: object 'h2o.targetencoder' not found

Tags: r, machine-learning, rstudio, h2o

I want to use: `h2o.targetencoder` function, then I do:

```
> install.packages("h2o")
> library("h2o")
> h2o.targetencoder
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: object 'h2o.targetencoder' not found
```

At the same time, I see that function is defined here:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/jenkins-rel-yau-5/h2o-r/h2o-package/R/targetencoder.R

Any idea on how can I use function: `h2o.targetencoder`?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of H2O are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely not using the latest version of H2O, please get it from out website h2o.ai/download or just run

install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-yau/5/R")

You can find an example here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/rel-yau/h2o-r/tests/testdir_algos/targetencoder/runit_targetencoder_model.R#L7